# WPF Expander OverrideMetadata IsExpandedProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to override the default value on the Expander for the IsExpanded property.

My code so far, which doesn't work:

```
static MyExpander()
{
    IsExpandedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyExpander), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
}
```

Still, the property is still set to false (which I checked like that to be sure):

```
public MyExpander()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"IsExpanded default value is: {IsExpandedProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue}");
}
```

**EDIT :** Nevermind, I'm just plain stupid, I did set the property to false in the style... Everything works fine now, thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the actual value instead of the `DefaultValue` from `DefaultMetadata`:

```
public MyExpander()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"IsExpanded value: {IsExpanded}");
}
```

From the Remarks section on the [DependencyProperty.DefaultMetadata Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.defaultmetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> The default metadata is the property metadata that is available to
>   that particular object or an object of a derived type where no
>   alternative metadata was supplied by an explicit Register or
>   OverrideMetadata call.

As the name suggests, `DefaultMetadata` does not return the overridden metadata.